# How to drop a database even if it is currently in use [Entity Framework]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a DbContextInitializer and I was inheriting from DropCreateDatabaseAlways<> however it wasn't working as desired.

```
public void InitializeDatabase(DbContext context)
{
    if (context.Database.Exists())
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
            $"ALTER DATABASE [{context.Database.Connection.Database}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
        context.Database.Delete();
        context.Database.Create();
    }
    else
    {
        context.Database.Create();
    }
}
```

The issue is when it gets to the ExecuteSqlCommand it tries to drop the database before running the command (debugging with SQL Profiler)

*Could someone let me know how to execute*

```
ALTER DATABASE [{context.Database.Connection.Database}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

*before it tries to drop the database?*

By the way, the dop command is sent when it hits the ExecuteSqlCommand line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the C# SQL Command:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string database = builder.InitialCatalog;

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring)) 
{
    con.Open();
    String sqlCommandText = @"
        ALTER DATABASE " + database + @" SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
        DROP DATABASE [" + database  + "]";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

---

Update: This script will kill all running processes and then drop the database I have just test it and it working:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server =.\; Database = UsersDatabase; Integrated Security = True; "))
{
  con.Open();
  var sqlCommandText = @"USE master 
                         DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = ''; 
                         SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';' 
                         FROM master..sysprocesses  
                         WHERE dbid = db_id('UsersDatabase') 
                         EXEC(@kill); 
                         ALTER DATABASE UsersDatabase  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
                         drop database UsersDatabase";
   var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

My database name is UsersDatabase and my SQL Server is .\ you have to change them! just hard coded your database/server name for testing and after the test you can read the connection string from the config file as the description in the previous section.

Comment: I tried using this and "got System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot drop database "DatabaseName" because it is currently in use" at the  ExecuteNonQuery line

Comment: are you sure you have the permissions to dorp the database can you do that with SSM?

Comment: and this code must not inside the DropCreateDatabaseAlways inherted class this code must be call from outside